# Understanding liferay's permission system

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet

I have already read all topics about liferay. I have read a lot of tutorials, but unfortunately i couldn't understand the concept of liferay permission.

I would be grateful if you could answer my questions.

Only i understand that liferay portlet has two types of permissions: `model` and `portlet`.

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<resource-action-mapping>

    <portlet-resource>

        <portlet-name>testFCK</portlet-name>

        <permissions>

            <supports>

                <action-key>ADD_FOO</action-key>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

                <action-key>DO_TRICS</action-key>

            </supports>

            <community-defaults>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

                <action-key>ADD_FOO</action-key>

            </community-defaults>

            <guest-defaults>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

            </guest-defaults>

            <guest-unsupported>

                <action-key>DO_TRICS</action-key>

            </guest-unsupported>

        </permissions>

    </portlet-resource>

    <model-resource>

        <model-name>me.pd.test.model.Foo</model-name>

        <portlet-ref>

            <portlet-name>testFCK</portlet-name>

        </portlet-ref>

        <permissions>

            <supports>

                <action-key>DELETE</action-key>

                <action-key>UPDATE</action-key>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

            </supports>

            <community-defaults>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

            </community-defaults>

            <guest-defaults>

                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

            </guest-defaults>

            <guest-unsupported>

                <action-key>UPDATE</action-key>

                <action-key>DELETE</action-key>

            </guest-unsupported>

        </permissions>

    </model-resource>

</resource-action-mapping>
```

I can use:

```
<action-key>ADD_FOO</action-key>

<action-key>VIEW</action-key>

<action-key>DO_TRICS</action-key>
```

in my portlet class to check if user has permission to do something like:

```
try {

    PortletPermissionUtil.check(themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker(), plid,  PortalUtil.getPortletId(actionRequest), "ADD_FOO");

} catch(PrincipalException e){

    System.out.println("NO ADD_FOO ACTION");

}
```

#### Question 1:

What does

```
<community-defaults>

     <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

     <action-key>ADD_FOO</action-key>

</community-defaults>

<guest-defaults>

    <action-key>VIEW</action-key>

</guest-defaults>
```

means? I create a community and add user(user1) to it and when i check user for permission he dosen't have it. Where should i use checking?

There are many example to use addResources before or after STORE enty to base:

```
resourceLocalService.addResources(foo.getCompanyId(),
                foo.getGroupId(), foo.getUserId(),
                Foo.class.getName(),
                foo.getPrimaryKey(), false,
                true, true);
```

#### Question 2:

Why should i use it and what do the following last 3 parameters mean? I can't understand which permission they give to Community or Guests?

```
ResourceLocalServiceUtil.addResources(
    entry.getCompanyId(), entry.getGroupId(), entry.getUserId(),BlogsEntry.class.getName(), entry.getPrimaryKey().toString(),
    false,
    addCommunityPermissions,
    addGuestPermissions);
```

How does `addResources` influence permissions on my entrys?

#### Question 3:

How i can use `<model-resource>`'s actions and when i should use it?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### re: question 1

The fragment in question are the default permissions assigned to *certain user types* to perform *certain actions* on resources. The resources, as in `ResourceLocalServiceUtil` and such, are extensions to other *real* objects in the database (e.g. `JournalArticle` or,  in your example, `me.pd.test.model.Foo`). So a  *resource* is something that has it's permissions   (i.e. permissions to execute actions on objects of resource  type) managed  by Liferay.

Although your object may have it's `groupId` or `companyId`, the resource related to it may have it's own values, and, unfortunately, it's programmer's role to keep these redundant resource values up-to-date.

The `community-default`  (in recent Liferay versions renamed to `site-member-defaults`) are default permissions assigned to members of the community (i.e. site) to which a particular resource belongs. So in your example, if you create some Bar object of Foo type in Baz community, the members of the Baz community should by default be assigned permissions to `ADD_FOO` and   `VIEW` the Bar object. That is, unless `addCommunityPermissions` in `addResource` method is false.

The  `guest-default` permissions are analogous,   just assigned to guest users by default  (and again, unless `addGuestPermissions` is false when creating the resource).

### re: question 2

So these last parameters  are `boolean portletActions, boolean addCommunityPermissions, boolean addGuestPermissions)`

The last two should already be easy to understand -- if you pass `false` to them, you effectively disregard the default action permissions defined in your permissions  XML.

The `portletActions` tell if you want to add permission resources related to the portlet itself (`true`) or to the portlet models (`false`).

Now  I am not 100% sure, but I think you shouldn't ever need to pass `portletActions` as true, as it is Liferay itself which should manage the portlet permission resources.

### re: question 3

Whenever your portlet manages some persisted objects  (think the `book-catalogue` portlet which comes up in many portlet tutorials, where you manage books in database etc.) and you want permissions on these objects to be managed through Liferay's resource permissions framework (you may choose not to and have these permissions managed some other way).

Comment: TY. It  helps lots. Always when i see some hook example( or ext)  they have a source of portlet code(****Wrapper.java or PortletStrutsAction.java) and only add smth to it. Where a can get a source?